# Hash to hide divs - direct access to page URL

Tags: jquery, css, url, html, hash

I am developing a website and I've run into the following issue.

My site consists of 4 pages all of which are just css div's that get hidden and shown based on a menu bar on the page.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/DcwUu/

HTML:

```
<button class="home-button">Home</button>
<button class="download-button">Download</button>
<button class="about-button">About</button>
<button class="contact-button">Contact</button>

<div class="home-container">
    <div class="left-corner"></div>
    This is the home page!
</div>

<div class="download-container">
    <div class="left-corner"></div>
    This is the download page!
</div>
<div class="about-container">
    <div class="left-corner"></div>
    This is the about page!
</div>
<div class="contact-container">
    <div class="left-corner"></div>
    This is the contact page!
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.home-button').click(
    function(){
        $('.home-container').show();
        $('.download-container').hide();
        $('.about-container').hide();
        $('.contact-container').hide();
    }
);
$('.download-button').click(
    function(){
        $('.download-container').show();
        $('.about-container').hide();
        $('.contact-container').hide();
        $('.home-container').hide();
    }
);
$('.about-button').click(
    function(){
        $('.about-container').show();
        $('.contact-container').hide();
        $('.download-container').hide();
        $('.home-container').hide();        
    }
);
$('.contact-button').click(
    function(){
        $('.contact-container').show();
        $('.home-container').hide();       
        $('.download-container').hide();
        $('.about-container').hide();
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
.download-container {display:none;}
.about-container {display:none;}
.contact-container {display:none;}
.home {display:block;}
```

My mainpage is index.php and I can access it by going to *localhost/mysite/index.php*

When I click any link and show/hide divs my URL changes to *localhost/mysite/index.php#*

I can't seem to find a way to directly access any of the 4 "pages" by a URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code or a relevant sample of it?

Comment: I was able to get this working with the answer by Louis and also the one from Brian.

Comment: Wesley - I have added my code to the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The poor man's way of doing it would be something like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
$('.page').hide();
$('#' + hash).show();
```

So, given a page like this,

```
<div class="page" id="main"></div>
<div class="page" id="foo"></div>
<div class="page" id="bar"></div>
<div class="page" id="baz"></div>
```

and if the user goes to `localhost/mysite/#foo`, then the `foo` page would be visible.

Comment: Thank you! I like the .slice to remove the # symbol. This was a difficult question to ask, as I didn't really know what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To get direct access, just find the hash in the URL:

```
var hash = window.location.hash
$(hash).show();
```

Depending on this value, show the correct div.

For changes on the loaded page listen for changes to the hash; jQuery provides you with a nifty `hashchanged` event:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  .. work ..
});
```

Inside of this event, extract your hash, which should be stored in `window.location.hash`. Depending on it's value, show/hide the corresponding div element.

See this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/3/

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I didn't understand. I'll try to be more specific with my questions in the future.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and I didn't know how to phrase it either. Luckily a Google search got me to this page. I think it should be reopened.